# Vert.x issue ( io/vertx/sqlclient/ClosedConnectionException)

Tags: java, sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, vert.x

I am trying to insert data into a table in SQL Server hosted on AWS RDS.

It was working fine and suddenly I started getting an issue. It seems like an intermittent issue but I am unable to see why it is this happening

> Fail to read any response from the server, the underlying connection might get lost unexpectedly.

This is how I am creating the database connection:

```
  public static MSSQLPool createMssqlDbPool(Vertx vertx, ConfigModel configModel) {

    MSSQLConnectOptions connectOptions = new MSSQLConnectOptions()
      .setHost(System.getenv().getOrDefault("DB_HOST", configModel.getDbConfig().getHost()))
      .setPort(Integer.parseInt(System.getenv().getOrDefault("DB_PORT", configModel.getDbConfig().getPort())))
      .setDatabase(System.getenv().getOrDefault("DB_NAME", configModel.getDbConfig().getDatabase()))
      .setUser(System.getenv().getOrDefault("DB_USER", configModel.getDbConfig().getUser()))
      .setPassword(System.getenv().getOrDefault("DB_PASSWORD", configModel.getDbConfig().getPassword()));

    // Pool options
    PoolOptions poolOptions = new PoolOptions()
      .setMaxSize(4);

    LOG.info("DB connection : {}", connectOptions.toJson());

    return MSSQLPool.pool(vertx, connectOptions, poolOptions);

  }
```

I thought the error might be because of version, so i changed the vert.x version from 4.3.8 to 4.4.0.
Now I am getting the error as

```
io/vertx/sqlclient/ClosedConnectionException
```

I have read threads on GitHub about adding timeout but they are not definitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out two solutions.

- We can reduce the version of mssql-client in vert.x to 4.3.1, which
  is compatible with the current RDS version of 15.00.4073.23.v1.
- Alternatively, we can keep the mssql-client version of vert.x at
  4.3.8 and upgrade the production database's RDS version to 15.00.4236.7.v1. Compatibility Chart

> ```
> Ms-sql Client 4.3.8 RDS(Sql server) 15.00.4236.7.v1
>               4.3.1                 15.00.4073.23.v1
> ```

Comment: how did you decide on these versions? are they documented somewhere?

Comment: I have not decided these version but while running code i found out that these are compatible.
4.3.1 works with both versions

Answer (score 0):

If you see this error it is likely a pooled connection has been idle for too long and closed by some intermediate proxy.

Change your pool options to close idle connections eagerly:

```
// Pool options
PoolOptions poolOptions = new PoolOptions()
  .setMaxSize(4)
  .setIdleTimeout(5)
  .setIdleTimeoutUnit(TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

5 minutes is just an example. The longer a connection lives, the better.

Comment: I tried this still i am getting the same issue. I am using vert.x 4.3.8.

Comment: Try setting IDLE timeout to an even lower value

Comment: I tried to set even 30 seconds still getting the issue. Not sure whats happening.

Comment: Can this be an issue with the number of connections already present for write

Comment: No, this failure is only reported when a network channel unexpectedly becomes inactive (closed).